# Jenkins Groovy parse json

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I got the following JSON:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
  },
  "stage": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
    "merge": "dev",
    "slackChannel": "#dg-test-deployments"
  },
  "master": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
    "merge": "stage",
  },
  "updates": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
    "merge": "master",
    "slackChannel": "#dg-test-deployments"
  }
}
```

And want to check if the keys *dev*, *stage*, *master* and *updates* exists.

Any advice how to do that in groovy ? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try e.g.:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
  "dev": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
  },
  "stage": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
    "merge": "dev",
    "slackChannel": "#dg-test-deployments"
  },
  "master": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
    "merge": "stage",
  },
  "updates": {
    "hoster": "123",
    "id": "123",
    "merge": "master",
    "slackChannel": "#dg-test-deployments"
  }
}'''
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
assert slurped.keySet().containsAll(['dev', 'stage', 'master', 'updates'])
```

Comment: I want to give this a try, but how could I do a "if" check on "assert slurped.keySet().containsAll(['dev', 'stage', 'master', 'updates'])" ?

Comment: You just need `if (slurped.keySet().containsAll(['dev', 'stage', 'master', 'updates']) { println 'whatever'}`

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

Pipeline supports `readJSON` and `writeJSON` [now](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace).

**Note**: plugin [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin) needs to be installed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46852563/11152683) for more info. Sample code can be found at [github sample](https://gist.github.com/sirius2k/e280089451e076070bdb4dae38c32051).

Comment: Minimalistic and effective.